# how to use seccomp_release libseccomp?

Tags: kernel, bpf, seccomp

Should I release the filter also after `seccomp_load()` is called? Or only if some of the calls to `seccomp_rule_add()` fails?

For example

**OPTION1**

```
r = seccomp_rule_add(...)
if r < 0 seccomp_relase(...)
r =seccomp_rule_add(...)
if r < 0 seccomp_relase(...)

seccomp_load(...)
```

**OPTION2**

```
r = seccomp_rule_add(...)
if r < 0 seccomp_relase(...)
r =seccomp_rule_add(...)
if r < 0 seccomp_relase(...)

seccomp_load(...)
seccomp_release(...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I release the filter also after `seccomp_load()` is called?

Yes, you should always release that state once you're finished with it. See the [`seccomp_load` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/seccomp_load.3.html) for an example code. Filters loaded in the kernel will remain active.

Comment: with always you mean "always when some call return error ?"

Comment: I mean always, whatever error is encountered and even if there are no errors.

Comment: because in the example you linked it's called just if there is an error right? . Also here https://www.paul-moore.com/docs/devconf-syscall_filtering-pmoore-012014-r1.pdf it's called just if there is an error. But I though I had to call it also after a successful call to seccomp_load

Comment: No, if there are no errors, execution goes through the `out` label anyway. It's a common coding pattern in C. It might be clearer with the following, even though there's no call to seccomp_load: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/seccomp_release.3.html.

Comment: And in the PDF you linked, on slide 9, it also goes through out if there are no errors.

Comment: so also without explictly call goto out it pass thorugh the label? In the slide 9 how can the code reach seccomp_release if it arrives to seccomp_load without executing goto out?

Comment: Yes it does. A label only marks a point of the program and goto are a shortcut (i.e., a jump) to that label. The code after a label can be executed without executing any goto statement.